# Hosting WPF and dynamically editing a workflow service at runtime?

Tags: wpf, workflow-foundation-4

Given a workflow service (testService.xamlx) that has a ReceiveRequest and a SendResponse (and nothing else for the moment), is it possible to have this service deployed to IIS and still be edited by a user (using a re-hosted WPF designer) with changes taking effect?

Essentially I want to throw my base service flow out and let users edit the workflow in a designer, hit save, and have the next invocation use the newly edited flow. I've figured out how to re-host the designer, but can't quite figure out how to load/edit/save a workflow service at runtime.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but the are some important restrictions. First of all you need to stop and restart the WorkflowServiceHost with the new workflow definition. Secondly all existing workflow instances in a persistence store will become invalid. In short this is only practical is there are very few and only short running workflows without persistence.

If you go this route you can just overwrite the XAMLX file, as it isn't compiled but used as is, and restart the WorkflowServiceHost to pick up the changes. Alternatively you can save the workflow to a XAML file, or any stream for that matter, and load it using the ActivityXamlServices. Next you can instantiate a WorkflowServiceHost using this workflow definition.